# Sorting Datatable int with mRender display

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm struggling with sorting of a column in my datatable.

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "decimal": ",",
                "thousands": " ",
                },
            "aoColumnDefs": [ {
                "aTargets": [7],
                "mRender": function(data, type, row){
                    rend = data.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
                    return rend;
                }
            }],
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm displaying numbers, as you can see in the screenshot :
[The sorting is messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B2fF.png)

I also tried parseInt but obviously it doens't work because it stops at the first "_".
I thought mRender was just affecting the display, but the sorting still interacts with it and messes up, so i added the language part and it doesn't cange anything.

If i just erase the mRender and Language, it displays the number normaly and sorts correctly, but it's not readable.

Any clue ? Most API for this are deprecated and DataTables doc says it should naturaly manage.

Comment: The [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function will assign the returned value to all of the display, sorting and filtering values used by DataTables, unless you specify additional logic in the function to handle [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). Something like `if ( type === 'display') { use one value } else { use a different value for sorting/filtering }`.

Comment: Side note: Unless you are using a very old version of DataTables, you can update your options (e.g. use `columnDefs` instead of `aoColumnDefs`).  See [Converting parameter names for 1.10](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).